# Get the result set from a table for each month of the selected date

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the result set from a table for each month of the selected date?
For e.g.: I wish to get one result set from a table to know when an event has occurred on each month of some particular date(suppose 10th of each month).

Comment: create table bazaartable (id int identity(1,1),dated datetime, amount money,username varchar(25))

Comment: What you have to do...display the result on particular day of each month or get the date based on any column value?...

Comment: second one. I want the date based on any column value.

Comment: What you want to get from table...for eg days of month having business over 1000 or what ,plz mention clearly...

Comment: I want to get those values of each month for that selected date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DAY() function

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DAY(your_field) = 10
```